# Azure File Share CIFS Mount Not Deleting File

Tags: files, samba, cifs

There's a file that's present on the Azure File Share mount that refuses to go away. It shows up in the directory:

```
ls -l foo
-rwxr-x---    0 bin      bin      1024 Aug 13 20:53 foo
```

However, trying to delete it doesn't work:

```
rm foo
rm: can't remove 'foo': No such file or directory
```

There also doesn't appear to be any open file handles to the file, at least on the host I'm on.

Trying to delete the file through the Azure Storage Explorer or Azure Portal fails with this error:

```
The specified resource is marked for deletion by an SMB client.
```

Trying to edit the file in any way via the portal leads to an interface error.

It's been stuck like this for a significant amount of time. Is there a way I can get more info at the OS level about the CIFS mount, and potentially get this file unstuck?

Here is the redacted mount info:

```
//foo.file.core.windows.net/bar on /bar type cifs (rw,relatime,vers=3.0,cache=strict,username=foo,domain=,uid=1,forceuid,gid=1,forcegid,addr=X.X.X.X,file_mode=0750,dir_mode=0775,soft,persistenthandles,nounix,serverino,mapposix,mfsymlinks,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,echo_interval=60,actimeo=1)
```

Comment: were you able to resolve the issue? I'm facing this problem right now...

Comment: @carbolymer I was not able to, unfortunately.

Comment: relevant GH issue: https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/1292

Comment: @carbolymer Much appreciated!